# how to add the register form in the center of the page and make it responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am newbie to bootstrap. I want my register form in the center of the webpage and it should be responsive.Please do tell me, how to make it responsive...Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="container">
  <!-- Begin Registration Form-->
  <form action="fillinfo.html" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="register" id="registerform">
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="salutation">Salutation  </label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <!--<input type="salutation" class="form-control sharp" id="salutation" name="salutation">-->
        <select type="text" class="form-control sharp input-xlarge" title="Select an option" id="salutation" name="salutation">
                                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="1">Dear Sir</option>
                                <option value="2">Dear Madam</option>
        </select>
      </div><!-- End col-xs-4-->  
    </div><!-- End form-group-->

      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="pwd">First Name  </label>
         <div class="col-xs-4">          
            <input type="text" class="form-control sharp input-xlarge" title="Enter Your first name" id="fname" name="fname">
         </div><!-- End col-xs-4-->  
      </div><!-- End form-group-->

    <div class = "form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="pwd">Middle Name  </label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control sharp input-xlarge" title="Enter Your middle name (optional)" id="mname" name="mname">
      </div><!-- End col-xs-4-->
    </div><!-- End form-group-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="pwd">Last Name  </label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control sharp input-xlarge" title="Enter Your last name" id="lname" name="lname">
      </div><!-- End col-xs-4-->
    </div><!-- End form-group-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="pwd">E-mail  </label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">          
        <input type="mail" class="form-control sharp input-xlarge" title="Enter a valid email address" id="email" name="email">
      </div><!-- End col-xs-4-->
    </div><!-- End form-group-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="pwd">Password  </label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control sharp" title="Enter Password" id="password" name="password">
      </div><!-- End col-xs-4-->
    </div><!-- End form-group-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="pwd">Confirm Password  </label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control sharp" title="Confirm Password" id="cpassword" name="cpassword">
      </div><!-- End col-xs-4-->
    </div><!-- End form-group-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-4 " for="pwd">Mobile Number  </label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">          
        <input type="text" class="form-control sharp" title="Enter your 10 digit mobile no" id="mobile" name="mobile">
      </div><!-- End col-xs-4-->
    </div><!-- End form-group-->

    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4">
        <div title="Agree our terms and conditions" class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="check"> I have read, Understood, and agreed to the <a style="color:#1A292E"  href="terms.html">Terms of Use</a> and the <a style="color:#1A292E" href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
        </div>
      </div><!-- End col-xs-4-->
    </div><!-- End form-group-->
</div><!-- End Container-->
```

Here, I am not able to make my register button as responsive..

```
<div class="container">
   <!-- Register modal with a button -->
  <button style="background: #042a36" type="button" class=" col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4 btn btn-info btn-lg sharp" title="Click to register" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="registerbtn">Register</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a block level button that takes up 100% of the width of its parent and putting it inside a grid column, e.g:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4">
        <button style="background: #042a36" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block sharp" title="Click to register" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="registerbtn">Register</button>
    </di>
</div>
```

Comment: @PrajwalKM what do you mean by it's not working? You should really put an example of your code up on jsfiddle.